# HDF5 package error compile

Tags: centos6, hdf5

I have compiled the `HDF5 package by GCC 4.9.2, CentOS 6.8 and std=c++11`, but I get error:

for `package Linux 3.10 CentOS 7 x86_64` I get :

```
./host/src/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

for `package Linux 2.6 CentOS 6 x86_64`  I get :

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/ld: warning: libsz.so.2, needed by ./host/src/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./host/src/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `SZ_encoder_enabled'
./host/src/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffCompress'
./host/src/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffDecompress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea to slove this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains that it is not finding `SZ_...` routines. szip is an optional library for HDF5 that you have to download separately.

Two options:

1. Re-configure hdf5 to disable szip
2. download, build and install szip

Comment: I installed but nothing changed, and I want the option one, how to disable szip ?

Comment: It depends on the build system. What version of hdf5 and what build system (autotools/cmake) are you using?

Comment: in fact I didnt install the package I just call it from makfile and the version is hdf5-1.8.18

Comment: please list the steps you have used to install hdf. Typically, I do something along the lines of 
`export CC=gcc ;
./configure --prefix /path/to/your/prefix ;
make` starting from a *fresh download* of hdf5 to avoid any cache or configuration issue.

Comment: I didnt install hdf, I just call it from makefile, did you get it ?

Comment: I got it, but you do not mention what makefile, at what location, how this makefile became available and what exact command you typed to obtain the result above.

Comment: After re-reading your error log and the reply by CompScien, I see that you try "package Linux 3.10 CentOS 7 x86_64" on cent os 6.8. This is bound to fail. Either you use a package specifically made for your exact distribution (architecture, version number, etc) or you have to build HDF5 from sources.

Comment: I us both of package. for CentOs 7 and CentOS 6.8 and I have the requirement to us the package of CentOS 7 in CentOs6.8 like GCC 4.8.5, and both of them I get different error,

Comment: for the makefile is for host code of FPGA, and I usded to compile it by typing make and now I'm working on host code need hdf5 package so I call it from makefile like that: 'LIB_DIRS := ./host/src/hdf5/lib' and the location doesnt metter.